# Getting an error on member function call

Tags: c++, function, pointers, function-calls

So I'm currently using the following code in the constructor of my class which has QMainWindow as a base:

```
char *name = this->windowTitle().toWCharArray;
```

The codes yields the following error:

```
error C3867: 'QString::toWCharArray': function call missing argument list; 
use '&QString::toWCharArray' to create a pointer to member
```

I'm not sure how to proceed so that I can get successfully obtain the window's title.

Comment: Searching on StackOverflow for this error code brings up other questions, including one with [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9525899/1281433).

Answer (score 6):

When you call a function you need to put () at the end:

```
char *name = this->windowTitle().toWCharArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

toWCharArray() is a function. Functions should be called by their name suffixed with (). This is the main rule in C for calling function. Otherwise it shows some exceptions. Call the method suffixed with () as follows:

char *name = this->windowTitle().toWCharArray();